# Should I remove previous state object in React.js after create new state object for keeping immutability?

Tags: reactjs, object, state

Previous State -> New State(at this moment should I remove previous state object?)
As I know, we don't have to change the state object directly for immutability.
So we have to create another state object. Right?
But in sample codes in github I didn't find remove part of previous object.
Is it okay for app's performance? Or react.js remove it automatically?

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a react job. Your task is only to initialize state when constructing the component - or else it will be null - and pass an object to `setState` that will be merged into the new state (new object).

Answer (score 0):

You only have to execute setState function in order to update state

Remember that you need to first initialize state in the constructor